# Rsync two file types in one command?

Tags: shell, rsync

How to write those into one line, also without repeat the same path?

```
rsync -a root@somewhere:/folder/remote/*.txt .
rsync -a root@somewhere:/folder/remote/*.jpg .
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I'd write it like this:

```
rsync -a root@somewhere:/folder/remote/*.{txt,jpg} .
```

Comment: This is a general technique that you can use with any command. The shell will repeat the argument, replacing the brace expression with each item in the list. It's called [brace expantion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Brace-Expansion)

Answer (score 18):

```
rsync -a --include='*.txt' --include='*.jpg' --exclude='*' root@somewhere:/folder/remote/ .
```

(Note that the final `/` in `/folder/remote/`, and the placement of `--exclude='*'` after the include rules, are important.) In shells that support brace expansion (e.g. bash, ksh, zsh):

```
rsync -a --include='*.'{txt,jpg} --exclude='*' root@somewhere:/folder/remote/ .
```

Add `--include='*/' --prune-empty-dirs` if you want to copy files in subdirectories as well.

Comment: rsync 3* seems to fail on * wildcards, the include|exclude work well though.

Comment: I'm trying to get this to work. Shouldn't the second single quotation mark be _after_ the brace expression, like this?:
`--include='*.{txt,jpg}'`

Comment: @mmortal03 No: the braces need to be expanded by the shell (they would have no meaning to rsync), whereas the asterisk needs to be passed to rsync (the shell wouldn't do anything useful with it).

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil', what you said works. Your explanation makes sense. It didn't occur to me that quotes would be, effectively, breaking the brace expansion syntax. Maybe it can be thought of as if the expansion is interpreted as if the quotes aren't there?

Comment: From elsewhere, courtesy of @Celada: "Brace expansion will never work inside quotes. Quoting removes the special meaning of { and } and many other characters. That's the whole point of quoting. If you want the characters to have their special meanings, don't quote them."
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/205903/can-bash-brace-expansion-be-performed-within-quotes#comment347287_205903