# Can bash brace expansion be performed within quotes

Tags: bash, brace-expansion

In an attempt to dry up my `bashrc`, I tried changing this,

```
CDPATH=".:~/Development:~/Development/resources:~"
```

to this,

```
CDPATH=".:~/Development{,/resources}:~"
```

But I found the brace expansion wasn't performed inside the quoted string. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Are you certain that `~` works? I know it doesn't work in quoted strings, nor after `:` even without quotes, but maybe CDPATH takes care of this for you.

Comment: No, brace expansion will never work inside quotes. Quoting removes the special meaning of `{` and `}` and many other characters. That's the whole point of quoting. If you want the characters to have their special meanings, don't quote them.

Comment: @Random832 Bash expands `~` in `PATH` and `CDPATH`. In `PATH`, this is rather unhelpful because other applications do not expand `~` and so if you do this, you PATH entries that only apply when bash is the one doing the lookup. For CDPATH, it's only bash doing the lookup so that's ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, actually there is:

```
set . ~/Development{,/resources} ~
IFS=:; CDPATH="$*"
```

The `"$*"` special parameter substitutes the first character in `$IFS` between each of the positional parameters. So if you `set` them and expand the arguments you want as separate arguments, you can then quickly fill in the appropriate delimiters as necessary on assignment.

If, as has been suggested might be the case, you could use some pointers on how to save/restore the value of `$IFS`, you might do the thing like:

```
CDPATH=$IFS
set . ~/Development{,/resources} ~
IFS=:${IFS+;IFS=\$CDPATH}
eval 'set "$*"; unset IFS'"
      $IFS;    CDPATH=\$1"
```

Sometimes a little juggle is worth it to keep the environment clean - and when a parameter affects the environment whether it is set or not - and in different ways depending - it probably is best to take care.

Still - such precautions are only really necessary in an environment in which you can guarantee no lasting control - in other words you don't need to do that in your own rc files. In a context like that you're pretty much guaranteed permanent control - and so you can *(and **should**)* set the special shell parameters to suit you.

Comment: Given that this is in response to a beginner shell scripting question, an answer that changes `$IFS` without restoring it is likely to cause more harm than good, and it would certainly cause issues if this snippet were incorporated into a larger script.  I'd suggest editing this to at least save and restore `IFS`.

Comment: @godlygeek - done

Comment: Well, this is good to know, but since the complexity of the solution far outstrips the amount of duplication it would eliminate, I'll just stick with the hard-coded original :)

Comment: @ivan - I'm sorry if I gave you the wrong impression - the last bit there was intended to *encourage you* to do other than I demonstrated. In your rcfile you should be doing `IFS='<space><tab><newline>'` - or whatever you want it to be - anyway. In fact - that's probably something worth checking for in a prompt function even. So the top bit is really what you *should do*, but maybe add `unset IFS` to the end there, and maybe do something in your prompt or elsewhere that will reset `$IFS` to a sane value if it is detected to be unset - like `PS1=${0##*["${PS1:= \t\n}$0"}$PS1` or something.